# Generic function given showing exception

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I wrote following repository function in the repository and it is not showing the data.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUser()
    {
        return await FindByCondition(ur => ur.IsDeleted != true).Include(x => x.UserRole.RoleType).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Generic function for this is:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return _mBHDbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
        }
```

It shows exception when writing the above code:

[image: Here is the exception screen sort]

This error comes when "include" is using with the query. Means when we need data from two tables the problem showing.

And my entity model structure is look like:

```
 public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            PatientAnswers = new HashSet<PatientAnswer>();
        }

        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int? UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataOfBirth { get; set; }

        public virtual RoleMaster UserRole { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientAnswer> PatientAnswers { get; set; }
    }
```

and other table structure is look like:

```
public partial class RoleMaster
    {
        public RoleMaster()
        {
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoleType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below. This brings the information inside linked `UserRole` entity and avoids a round trip when accessing `RoleType`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUser()
    {
        return await FindByCondition(ur => ur.IsDeleted != true).Include(x => x.UserRole).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThenInclude` like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUser()
{
    return await FindByCondition(ur => ur.IsDeleted != true)
      .OrderBy(ro => ro.UserId)
      .Include(x => x.UserRoleNavigation)
      .ThenInclude(ur => ur.RoleType)
      .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It complains about `Include(x => x.UserRole.RoleType)` expression.

Include expect lambda poiting navigation property to include, so as I see it it's `x.UserRole`.

Moreover it does not make sense to `Inlucde` value property, such as string. If you want to access it (fetch it from db), it's enought to include navigation property that contains it, so after all, you need only `Include(x => x.UserRole)`